# plt.pause(0) never returns, even if I close the window

Tags: python, matplotlib

TL;DR How can I return to terminal prompt when my scripts ends with `plt.pause(0)` ??

---

This is my code, a sort of animation w/o `matplotlib.anim`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from sys import exit

def websocket(tmax=1000, dt=0.005):
    from numpy import sin
    from time import sleep
    w1 = 0.3 ; w2 = 0.4 ; slope = 0.0025
    for t in range(0, tmax):
        sleep(dt)
        yield slope*t + 0.5*(sin(w1*t)-sin(w2*t))

t, y = [], []
tmin = 0 ; dtmax = 101

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 2), dpi=96, layout='tight')
line = ax.plot(0, 0)[0]
ax.set_ylim(-1, 4)
ax.set_xlim(tmin, tmin+dtmax)

for t_, y_ in enumerate(websocket(400, dt=0.002)):
    t.append(t_), y.append(y_)
    tmin = max(tmin, t_-dtmax)
    line.remove()
    ax.set_xlim(tmin, tmin+dtmax)
    line = Line2D(t[tmin:tmin+dtmax],
                                   y[tmin:tmin+dtmax])
    ax.add_line(line)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)

if True:
    plt.pause(0)
else:
    plt.pause(4)
```

When I run with `pause(0)` it hangs displaying the window, with which I can interact as expected, but when I close th e plot window (either via the window manager or using the "q" keybinding), the script hangs forever until I enter `^C` in the controlling terminal, at that point I get the following backtrace

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boffi/ppp.py", line 31, in <module>
    plt.pause(0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 557, in pause
    canvas.start_event_loop(interval)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py", line 407, in start_event_loop
    with _maybe_allow_interrupt(event_loop):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 144, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 269, in _maybe_allow_interrupt
    old_sigint_handler(*handler_args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

If I run with `pause(4)` and I close the window immediately after completion, the script stays still for about 4" and eventually I have the terminal prompt.

How can I return to terminal prompt when my scripts ends with `plt.pause(0)` ??

---

PS I understand that the correct solution probably won't end with `plt.pause(0)`.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Just edit the file, `g/if/s/True/False/`

Comment: If you look at the imports, you'd possibly guess that I have played with `sys.exit()` to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

After thinking of what `pause(0)` is doing, i.e., activating the input loop and waiting forever, I realized that `show()` does the same, but is designed to do proper housekeeping and return control to the interpreter when the plot window is closed, either via window manager or using the "q" shortcut.

To have the expected behaviour, I edited my source file in `vim` and I used the `vim` command

```
:g/pause(0)/s/pause(0)/show()/|wq
```